# How do i read a JSON file content using POLLENRICH

Tags: java, apache-camel, mapping

I'm working with Apache camel version 2.24.3 and this is my JSON file content

```
{
  "p-1":"smh_5000",
  "p-2":"smh_6000"
}
```

So i want to read this content file using pollenrich: when i give him p-1,he returns smh_5000.
May someone please advice on how to use pollenrinch with this example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<camelContext> 
<pollEnrich id="readFile" timeout="5000"> 
                <constant>file://data?fileName=test.json</constant> 
            </pollEnrich> 
     <log id="jsonData" message="The message contains ${body}"/> 
     <process id="readingparams" ref="ReadingP"/> 
</camelContext>
```

and my process is :

```
public class ReadingP implements Processor { 
    @Override 
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception,JSONException {
                JSONObject json = (new JSONObject(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class))).getJSONArray("catalogue").getJSONObject(0);
                Map<String,Object> ctx= exchange.getProperties();
                ctx.put("product-p", json.get("p-1"));
                exchange.getOut().setHeaders(exchange.getIn().getHeaders());
         }
}
```